# Tell methods of base class to use more restricted type hints in a derived class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, types, type-hinting

### Scenario

Lets say I have a generic `Store` class that implements various methods to retrieve `StoreObjects`. And to fill the store it defines an abstract method `load_object`.

Then I create a `CarStore`. I derive from the `Store` and overwrite the `load_object` method to return `Car` objects.

Now the question is how to add type hints for this. First the code:

```py
from typing import Dict
import weakref
import abc


class StoreObject:
    pass


class Car(StoreObject):
    def __init__(self, color: str):
        self.color = color  # type: str


class Store(abc.ABC):
    def __init__(self):
        self._cache = weakref.WeakValueDictionary()  # type: weakref.WeakValueDictionary[int, StoreObject]

    def get(self, index: int) -> StoreObject:
        try:
            return self._cache[index]
        except KeyError:
            obj = self.load_object(index)
            self._cache[index] = obj
            return obj

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def load_object(self, index: int) -> StoreObject:
        raise NotImplementedError


class CarStore(Store):
    def load_object(self, index: int) -> Car:
        if index < 100:
            return Car("red")
        else:
            return Car("blue")


store = CarStore()
car = store.get(10)
print("Your car color is", car.color)
```

### Type Checking Errors

The problem is in the following line:

```py
print("Your car color is", car.color)
```

Here `PyCharm` gives the following warning:

```
Unresolved attribute reference 'color' for class 'StoreObject'
```

`Mypy` gives the following error:

```py
development/storetyping.py:39: error: "StoreObject" has no attribute "color"
```

Also the `PyCharm` code completion does obviously not include the `name` method for `store.get(10).?`.

## Question

How can I type the base class such that `PyCharm` and `mypy` can successfully check this code?

Is there a way to parameterize the types in `Store` such that when creating `CarStore` I can tell it to use `Car` instead of `StoreObject` in the annotations?

Comment: Why are you using weakref? In the code pasted I see no benefit to it. If you want a simple cache just use `from functools import lrucache` but even then you aren't doing any heavy computations here that require a cache.

Comment: Also type hinting in no way restricts types nor does it help linters.  It is merely a documentation tool.

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse The behaviour I want is that the store does not hold any objects that are not referenced from the outside. An lrucache is not achieving this.

Comment: What holds on to the reference of the Car object? If nothing holds a reference then it will be deleted.

Comment: That is true, by itself typhints are not doing anything. And still there are libraries like `mypy` that use type hints for static typing and linters like `Jedi` that use those type hints in that way.

Comment: This is really a bit off topic, but for an lru cache, the lru cache will hold a reference to all N (by default 128) previously returned items.

Comment: Correct. It is not appropriate for your use-case after seeing your last comment. That being said I am still confused which object holds all the references to the `StoreObject` so they don't get deleted.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197955/discussion-between-chris-and-error-syntactical-remorse).

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse: Think of the `StoreObject` cache as being like parking spaces at a car dealer; if nothing is there, `get` "parks a car there", and as long as someone is still using the parked car, anyone who visits that space gets the same car. When no one is using that car anymore, the car is disposed of. All the cache does is prevent two cars from being parked in the same space.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In more static languages you would create `Store` as a generic class and use `Car` as a type parameter when inheriting from `Store`.

We can actually do that using the `typing` module in python.

Here is a minimal example:

```
from typing import Generic, TypeVar


T = TypeVar('T')  # this is the generic placeholder for a type

# Store is a generic class with type parameter T
class Store(Generic[T]):
    def get(self) -> T:  # this returns a T
        return self.load_object()

    def load_object(self) -> T:  # this also returns a T
        raise NotImplementedError


class Car:
    def __init__(self, color):
        self.color = color

# Now we inherit from the Store and use Car as the type parameter
class CarStore(Store[Car]):
    def load_object(self):
        return Car('red')


s = CarStore()
c = s.get()
print(c.color)  # Code completion works and no warnings are shown
```

**Edit:**

To address ShadowRanger's note: If you want Car and all the products to have a common base class you can use the `bound` parameter of the `TypeVar`. Thank you juanpa.arrivillaga for the hint.

So we create a Product class and bind the `TypeVar` to it.

```
class Product:
    def get_id(self):
        raise NotImplementedError

T = TypeVar('T', bound=Product)
```

Mypy will now complain about this:

```
class CarStore(Store[Car]):
    def load_object(self):
        return Car('red')
```

because a `Car` is not a `Product`. So let' change that, too:

```
class Car(Product):
    def get_id(self):
        return ...

    def __init__(self, color):
        self.color = color
```

And now, mypy is happy.

**Edit2**:

Here is the full code with some more annotations, that make even `mypy --strict` happy.

```
from typing import Generic, TypeVar


class Product:
    def get_id(self) -> int:
        raise NotImplementedError


T = TypeVar('T', bound=Product)


class Store(Generic[T]):
    def get(self) -> T:
        return self.load_object()

    def load_object(self) -> T:
        raise NotImplementedError


class Car(Product):
    def get_id(self) -> int:
        return hash(self.color)

    def __init__(self, color: str):
        self.color = color


class CarStore(Store[Car]):
    def load_object(self) -> Car:
        return Car('red')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = CarStore()
    c = s.get()
    print(c.color)
```

Comment: I was looking at doing something like this, but I'm unclear on how to enforce that all versions of `T` obey an interface; in the OP's case, `StoreObject` provides no interface, but in a real case, I'd assume `StoreObject` provides some common functionality, and `Car` extends it. I don't have PyCharm to experiment with, so I've just been using `mypy --strict`, which does require a return annotation of `-> Car` for `load_object` in `CarStore`; I haven't found a way to say that `T` must be `StoreObject` or a subclass thereof though.

Comment: @ShadowRanger you can use a bounded type variable

Comment: @ShadowRanger, im not a mypy expert (i want to change that however), but now it seems to be happy. With `--strict` is still complains. Initially i didn't use mypy, because OPs question was about PyCharm.

Comment: @Wombatz: Don't know how I missed the `bound` argument while reading about `covariant`/`contravariant`. Sigh... Good answer!

Comment: @Wombatz This is exactly what I was looking for! I thought about C++ templates all the time, but didn't knew you can use generics as a baseless for "normal" classes. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 2):

Your type checking is behaving correctly; `get` is not overridden in `CarStore`, so the annotation on it continues to specify that it returns `StoreObject`. If you want to change the annotation, you'd have to redefine `get` in `CarStore`, e.g. by adding:

```
def get(self, index: int) -> Car:
    return typing.cast(Car, super().get(index))
```

Make sure to `import typing` to gain access to `cast` (or use unqualified `cast` and add it to your `from typing import Dict` import).

To avoid runtime performance overhead, you could only conditionally define `get` based on an `if typing.TYPE_CHECKING:` test (which returns `True` when static checkers are analyzing the code, and `False` when running it), so the `get` overload isn't actually defined at runtime.

Comment: Thanks! I tried the redefinition, but without the casting. Now it works!

Comment: @Chris: You're welcome. The other approach would be to avoid the redefinition, and have callers who actually need the `Car` interface perform the cast themselves, e.g. `car = typing.cast(Car, store.get(10))`; it's more verbose, but faster (less runtime wrapping), and it encourages sticking to the `StoreObject` interface by default; after all, if you're inheriting from an interface, in theory you want to be able to swap to another version of the interface without breaking things, and relying on `Car` specific stuff makes all other `Store` implementations unusable.

Comment: Thats true. My intention for creating the store class was more to abstract out the bookkeeping (which in reality is much more complex) and not for it to be used as an interface.
And yes it would be cool to actually be able to annotate store, as we would annotate a dict as `store = CarStore()  # type: CarStore[StoreObject]` vs. `store = CarStore()  # type: CarStore[Car]`. As I can see uses for both and your answer would restrict us to the later.

Comment: @Chris: You might be able to make this work with [user-defined generics](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#user-defined-generic-types) then. I've experimented a bit, and came up with something similar to [Wombatz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57500669/364696), but haven't found a way to ensure subclasses of `Store` only hold subclasses of `StoreObject`.

Comment: @Chris: Somehow I missed the `bound` argument for `TypeVar`; with it, your code can be made to work without explicit overrides. Assuming it works for you, I think you should give Wombatz's answer the check mark; it's much closer to your intent (to allow subclasses to specialize their return type to a subclass of `StoreObject` without requiring them to override both methods).